# Sum of MatrixPreview columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have to create the following MatrixPreview:

`Month   january                   february
Desc      Value    sum_Value         Value     sum_Value
DescA      V_A     V_A + V_B + V_C    V_X    V_X + V_Y + V_Z
DescB      V_B     V_A + V_B + V_C    V_Y    V_X + V_Y + V_Z
DesC       V_C     V_A + V_B + V_C    V_Z    V_X + V_Y + V_Z`

This is my data relationship:
[image: relationship]

These are my fields:

[image: fields]

And this is my table:
[image: table]

I have to create a new measure or column that contains a DAX formula to sum all the values by month. How can I that using my data?

Comment: If I understand correctly you need the sum of all values in each month .Doesn't the sum_Value for february should be `V_X + V_Y + V_Z`?

Comment: Oh.. yes, I'm sorry, thank you @alejandrozuleta. I will edit my question.

Comment: If obj_id will be the same for january and february, How do you know which values correpond to which month? sample data would be useful.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, I edited my question. I think now it is fine. Thanks for your pacience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `ALL('GRUPO DE DESPESA'[NOME_DESPESA])`.

Create a measure like this:

```
First SM = CALCULATE(SUM('GRUPO DE DESPESA'[VRTOTAL]),
ALL('GRUPO DE DESPESA'[NOME_DESPESA]))
```

**UPDATE:** As you have two columns in the Rows pane of your matrix you have to include both columns in the `ALL()` function:

```
First SM = CALCULATE(SUM('GRUPO DE DESPESA'[VRTOTAL]),
ALL('GRUPO DE DESPESA'[DESCGRUPO],'GRUPO DE DESPESA'[NOME_DESPESA]))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Caaarlos, I've updated my answer give it a try. Good luck.